# How to distinguish between full/partially intersecting Collider2D?

Tags: unity, physics, box2d

I'm using Unity 5 to make 2D game.

I have a screen (gray), arena (green) and player-controlled object (yellow) that can be moved across the screen with mouse before placement:
[image]

There is no Rigidbody2D attached to arena or object.

Is it possible to check whether the object is fully inside the arena or partially inside it **using built-in Unity physics API**?

I know that it can be easily calculated in this case, but I want to know, is it ever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably already know based on how you formulate your question, the physics engine only registers collisions whn at least one of the colliders have a rigidbody attached. In many cases you can just add a kinematic rigidbody that is not affected by gravity to get a collision detection going. Unfortunately the Collision2D.ContactPoints, which is of type [ContactPoint2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContactPoint2D.html), do not let you know the [interpenetration](http://www.cem.brighton.ac.uk/staff/alb14/CI322/Lectures%20&%20Tutorials/Physical%20Simulation/Week10_Havok1.htm)  amount so you'll need to decide the entirely inside part yourself.

If adding a kinematic rigidbody is not a possible solution for you there is actually one other approach to using the physics engine. If you check the static methods of the [Physics2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.html) class you'll notice that there are several methods named "cast", e.g. [CircleCast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.CircleCast.html). These actually **can** be used to check even against static colliders with no rigidbodies. They all return a [RaycastHit2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D.html) which will not tell you if the entire cast was inside the collider so you'll still have to figure that part out yourself.

A third possible solution would be to use a custom collider to create a collider that covers the areas around your "arena". This could be done using e.g. the [edge collider](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-EdgeCollider2D.html) to create a circle around the arena. It will only create a set of edges though, so you'll also need to check that the collider you want to check for is not entirely outside (e.g. by circle cast against a circle collider in this case).